# option clash for tocloft

Tags: pdftex, subfloats

I have the following packages:

```
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,graphicx} 
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft} 
\usepackage{epstopdf,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algorithmic} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{url}
```

If I just keep the  `subfigure` package, I get error that `c\@lofdepth` and `c\@lotdepth` already defined.

Can you please help?

Comment: The `subfigure` option to `tocloft` includes the `subfigure` pacakge, so you don't need `\usepackage{subfigure}`.

Comment: Yes, that is commented out. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: 1st I just had subfigure, and got the c\@lofdepth error. Now, when I added tocloft, I get the error that option clash for tocloft.

Comment: It seems that the `\usepackage{subfigure}` is required in my case, and compiles fine. I get `\l@subfigure undefined` if I don't include it.  Perhaps you have older versions of the packages?

Comment: I am using \documentclass[print]{nuthesis}   The class file is available here, if that helps. http://www.math.unl.edu/graduate/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your document class is derived from the `memoir` class, which emulates many packages, including `tocloft` (see chapter 9 of [the manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf)), and has features comparable to `subfig` (see section 10.9). So consider dropping the extra packages, or using memoir's \DisemulatePackage command (see section 18.24) if you really just have to load them. Here's an example using subfigures that compiles fine for me on TeX Live 2011:

```
\documentclass{nuthesis}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{url}

\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{One}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
Figure content goes here
\subcaption{First figure}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
Figure content goes here
\subcaption{Second figure}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Verbatim texts}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \documentclass[print]{nuthesis}  I think it is a customized class file. I have given the link in the previous comment. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your base document class is derived from the [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class (as is the thesis class I maintain). `memoir` already emulates many other packages, including `tocloft` (see chapter 9 of [the manual)](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf), and has features comparable to `subfig` (see section 10.9). So consider dropping the extra packages, or using `memoir`'s `\DisemulatePackage` command (see section 18.24) if you really just have to load them.

Comment: Editing answer to account for different document class.